# C++ member function callback and object lifetime

Tags: c++, c++11, callback

I have a zeromq subscriber class that handles events from any of my connectes publisher services. This works well but now I want class member function callbacks. The specific class which contains all the member functions has the subscriber class as a member but how to manage object lifetime when registering member functions in the subscriber class.

I do not know exactly how to name this problem but imagine the following situation:

1. The subscriber class has a data structure that holds all callbacks. This is quite easy to implement using lambdas and `std::function` for binding to class members.
2. The class containing the subscriber class is destructed and goes into the destructor. After the destructor, all members (including the subscriber) are destroyed. This is the situation which is critical because the server is still able to send some data and the subscriber is still alive after the destructor has been called but calling a member function after the destructor might be dangerous.

How would you handle this situation?

Edit 1:
Here is some mockup.

```
class Subscriber {
public:
  Subscriber(const std::string &server);

  void subscribe(const std::string &topic, 
    std function);

}

class SomeClass {
public:
  SomeClass();
  virtual ~SomeClass();



private:
  Subscriber sub;
}
```

SomeClass may do whatever it wants and register some handlers.

Comment: While I can roughly imagine how the structure might look like it is hard to tell without a [mcve], as the exact dependencies, relations and lifetimes are not clear. So giving a meaningful answer is not really possible.

Comment: How about making your subscriber class a static/singleton that's valid until program's lifetime?

Comment: @srinivirt solving such a problem with statics/singleton potentially only hides a conceptual design problem and has the risk that the problem arises again at a later point when the project grows. I'm not entirely against static or singleton, but I think they are usually chosen for the wrong reason.

Comment: Usually, whatever class owns the connection to the server (or the queue handle, or whatever keeps the event source open) would also own event listeners. This way, listeners live as long as the source.

Comment: @Igor Yes that is true but what if the event source fires the events from inside separate threads? There is a condition where the SomeClass destructor ends and all owned objects get destroyed. When the destructors has finished there is still a possibility that some threads might fire an event while the Subscriber class is still alive. This is the problem I want so solve.

Comment: Such a source should provide a way to gracefully close the connection, so that there's a distinct point in time after which no more events would be coming, and it's safe to dispose of resources associated with that connection.